# How to turn off drag slide in Vue agile

Tags: vue.js, carousel

I am using vue-agile, and I have to show videos and images in it. The images work fine but for videos, whenever I drag the pointer to move to a certain position in the player, the slider drags and moves to the next slider. Is there any way to stop the drag/swipe feature. Thanks.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-agile

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I first watch the mouse events on the clicked element (@mousedown, @mouseup)
On mousedown, I set the swipe-distance prop to a very high pixel value in the example below I used 1,000,000,000 (Default is 50).
Doc: https://github.com/lukaszflorczak/vue-agile
This worked for my case.

```html
<template>
    <agile :dots="false" :infinite="false" :center-mode="true" 
      :nav-buttons="false" :swipe-distance="noSweep ? 1000000000 : 50" >
      <div v-for="(card, index) in cards" :key="index">
        <div 
          @mousedown="noSweep=true"
          @mouseup="noSweep=false"
        >
        Card content - example
        </div>
      
    </agile>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      noSweep: false,
      cards:['A','B','C']
    }
  }
}
</script>
```